# Open shapefile in iOS with GDAL

Tags: gdal, shapefile, error, ios

I'm trying to open a shapefile on iOS with GDAL 2.2.2 and getting error 4 :

```
GDALDataset  *poDS;
GDALAllRegister();
poDS = (GDALDataset *) GDALOpen( filename.UTF8String, GA_ReadOnly );
if( poDS == NULL )
{
    NSLog(@"%@", @"Open failed." );
    return;
}

ERROR 4: /Users//Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6AB03125-4ECB-4BD3-BBBF-C5D50FCD6058/data/Containers/Data/Application//Documents/html/grafoCiclabile_polyline/ not recognized as a supported file format.
```

The shapefile is downloaded and written in document folder by the apps, so that it should not be a permission problem ; and with previous versions of GDAL / iOS , with the same files, it worked.

The shapefiles can be downloaded from here:
https://alessandrotrebbi.com/hsl/zipdownload.php?rootpath=BikeNav4Mi

Is it possible that they are in an old format no longer supported?

Comment: There is only one shapefile format, but it is made up of (at least) three files with the same prefix.

Comment: sorry, should work now, it's a development server and goes down here and then...folder contains 4 files: dbf prj shp she , I include file sizes   616891   grafoCiclabile_polyline.dbf
    382   grafoCiclabile_polyline.prj
  216492   grafoCiclabile_polyline.shp
   13324 grafoCiclabile_polyline.shx

Comment: In my own iOS app (using GDAL 2.2.2), I can install this shapefile from the download link).  However, my app (which relies on EPSG codes) cannot determine a spatial reference system for the shapefile (which means that when it creates an GDAL SRS, it cannot get the authority code from that SRS) - is it a custom SRS?.  It does recognise the shapefile as a valid dataset though and opens fine (as far as GDAL is concerned).

Comment: PS.  I notice that QGIS is able to get the SRS as EPSG 1660.